# How to get the network buffer usage of some process

Tags: networking, buffer

I have an Ubuntu server, which contains some user-processes.

It always crashes after starting-up several hours. "crashes" means that I cannot neither ssh to it nor ping it anymore.

I'm doubting that some processes exhausted the buffer of network, meaning that some process sent so many data or so huge data that the network cannot hold it.

How could I prove it?

I've known about how to get some basic config info about network: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/

However, I don't know how to get the usage of network buffer of some process.

Comment: Why network? Java?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro   C++.

Comment: You do not exaust network...there can be others factors at play. In the past

Comment: Sorry, was mobile, now at keyboard. In the past, I had a SSL frontend with a site a couple millions of access per month with ssh going down on me without no apparent reason...I did CPU pinning, Linux 2 CPUs for Linux, the app doing the SSL frontend  with 2 CPUs for it alone, never heard about that machine becoming with SSH down again.